# Bluetooth and WiFi do not connect on Pavillion 15 HP

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, hp

I have a new Pavilion 15 AMD Radeon with a RTL8723be chip and it is recognized, but the Bluetooth is not working. It appears but never finds or shows anything.

I tried a lot of distributions and kernels, but nothing happened, what can I do? Going back to Windows 8 is not an option.

Comment: I don't know if it will ever work, the only chance is https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723au_bt

Answer (score 0):

For the wifi, it does help if your access point is set to a single channel instead of auto and use WPA2 only with AES, no WEP or TKIP

The backported drivers might work better than the ones with your current kernel, see instructions http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=187963&start=20#p974596

One thing you need to do before backports is `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential`